# For and If together - dataframe Python

Tags: python, dataframe

If the value in column 'y' is K, multiply the column 'x' values to 1e3. If column 'y' is M, multiply the column 'x' values to 1e6. Below code multiplies all the values to with 1e3

```
value_list = []
for i in list(result['x'].values):
    if np.where(result['y'] == 'K'):
        value_list.append(float(i)*1e3)
    elif  np.where(result['y'] == 'M'):
        value_list.append(float(i)*1e6)
    else:
        value_list.append(np.nan)
df['Value_numeric'] = value_list
df.head().Value_numeric
```

Dataframe:
[image: Result dataframe:]

Output right now:
[image: Output right now:]

Comment: Can you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with input data and your expected output?

Comment: I have edited the question. column x has the amount. I need to convert it into same unit.

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.  Your posted code does not run.  We also expect that you will trace the offending values just before the point of error. Where are you confused about how they got to those values?

Comment: [Include your data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246/how-to-provide-a-reproducible-copy-of-your-dataframe-with-to-clipboard) as part of the example.

Comment: Why are you doing this with a `for` loop and `if` checks instead of a simple broadcast command with conditional filters?

Comment: How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This case is simple enough that it's not necessary to use a loop or a custom function; one can use a simple assignment:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = {'x': [750, 5, 4, 240, 220], 'y': ['K', 'M', 'M', 'K', 'K']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

# here is the main operation:
df['value_numeric'] = np.where(df['y']=='K', df['x'] * 1e3, df['x'] * 1e6)
print(df)
```

output

```
     x  y  value_numeric
0  750  K       750000.0
1    5  M      5000000.0
2    4  M      4000000.0
3  240  K       240000.0
4  220  K       220000.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,"a"],[2,'b'],[3,'c']], columns=['A', 'B'])

def calc(x):
    if x['B'] == 'a':
        return x['A'] * 10

    if x['B'] == 'b':
        return x['A'] * 20

    if x['B'] == 'c':
        return x['A'] * 30

df['calculate'] = df.apply(lambda x: calc(x),axis=1)

print(df)


#   A  B  calculate
#0  1  a         10
#1  2  b         40
#2  3  c         90
```

You can adjust your calculations as needed based on the condition.